# How do I construct a type that describes a mutation made on a function parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Lets say I have this function written in javascript:

```
//index.js
function foo(obj) {
  obj['bar'] = 'biz';
}
module.exports.foo = foo;
```

How would I create a typescript definition for this?

I've tried using the `is` operator:

```
//index.d.ts
export function foo<T>(obj: T): T is T & { bar: string }
```

But I can't seem to get the type system to recognize `bar` as a valid key on whatever I pass to `foo`.

How would i do this?

Comment: The return type should be `obj is...` instead of `T is...`. But a type guard function must return a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type guard impacts the type of a parameter and must return a boolean. So a valid implementation would be:

```
function foo<T>(obj: T): obj is T & { bar: string }{
    obj['bar'] = 'biz';
    return true;
}

let o = { foo: "string" }
if(foo(o)) {
    o.bar //valid
    o.foo //valid
}
```

Unfortunately there isn't an assertion mode to type guards. A type guard must return a `booelan` and be used in an `if` statement to impact the type of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer provided by @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I ended up doing it like this:

```
function foo<T>(obj: T): obj is T & { bar: string }{
    obj['bar'] = 'biz';
    return true;
}

const obj = { foo: "string" }
if(!foo(obj)) throw 'This will never happen';

o.bar //valid
o.foo //valid
```